# React native with android project unable to build :react-native-share

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

FPTECHS044s-MacBook-Pro:android prabhudas$ ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-share'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-share:classpath'.
  >   Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar
  >   Could not download protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.1.2)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.1.2/protos-26.1.2.jar'.
  >   Could not HEAD 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.1.2/protos-26.1.2.jar'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s

```js
repositories {
//        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    
    
    
    
    allprojects {
    repositories {
//        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        jcenter()
        /*maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }*/
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
//            url "/Users/prabhudas/StudioProjects/TilaWithReactJS/node_modules/react-native/android"
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        /*maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }*/
    }
}
```

Every time I run **sudo react-native run-android**

```js
/Users/prabhudas/StudioProjects/TilaWithReactJS/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:90
                    throw err0;
                    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/prabhudas/StudioProjects/TilaWithReactJS/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/.cache'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:776:3)
    at sync (/Users/prabhudas/StudioProjects/TilaWithReactJS/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at sync (/Users/prabhudas/StudioProjects/TilaWithReactJS/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at sync (/Users/prabhudas/StudioProjects/TilaWithReactJS/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at save (/Users/prabhudas/StudioProjects/TilaWithReactJS/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/cache.js:50:20)
    at internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:70:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:47:5)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:300:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:826:3)
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window

logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Please add some context to explain the code sections.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Could you please check the content now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this Commands May Help You (Try it!) :

```
Step 1: npm uninstall react-native-share --save-dev

Step 2: npm install --save react-native-share

Step 3: npm link

Step 4: npm link react-native-share

Step 5: Killall node -9

Step 6: react-native run-android
```

Comment: you just need to link your project